# Раскрывающийся TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

Требуется сделать TextView.
Грубо говоря, есть количество символов.
Если оно больше (к примеру) 200, то создается кликабельный текст "показать полностью", по клику которого открывается полный текст.
Как реализовать подобное?

Comment: нужно программировать. стандартными средствами не создашь такое.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать раскрывающийся TextView?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1024831/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-textview)