# Как сделать раскрывающийся TextView?

Tags: java, android

Требуется сделать TextView. Есть количество символов. Если оно больше (к примеру) 200, то создается кликабельный текст "показать полностью", по клику которого открывается полный текст. Как реализовать подобное?

Comment: есть [готовые библиотеки](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+expandable+textview&type=)

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант, можно при создании textView задавать обрезанный текст, дописывая в конце "показать полностью...", а затем повесить на него слушатель нажатия, по которому текст будет становиться полным. Что-то вроде:

```
<...> //OnCreate
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //Получаем полный текст
        String fullText = getResources().getString(R.string.text);
        String showContent = "Показать полностью...";
        int maxLength = 200;
        //При необходимости обрезаем и вешаем слушатель
        if (fullText.length() > maxLength) {
            fullText = fullText.substring(0, maxLength - showContent.length()) + showContent;
            textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((TextView) v).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text));
                }
            });
        }
        textView.setText(fullText);
<...>
```